# get category name in admin screen

Tags: categories

I want to get the name of the category that I am editing posts in. So I have this code that I found here

```
 function add_custom_submenus() {
  global $submenu, $post;
  $submenu['edit.php'][] = array(
__('Back'), // menu title
'edit_posts', // menu cap
'edit.php?category_name=' . $category_name // menu link
  );
}
```

My link shows great. I know the page that I need to go back to. I am just having trouble finding the name of the page.

The admin screen shows

```
 edit.php?category_name=band-member
```

band-member is the name of the category that I am editing posts in. So I was trying to create a link back to the band-member posts page. I can't figure out the php to get the name of the category of the current post that I am editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_custom_submenus', 9999 );
function add_custom_submenus()
{
    global $submenu;

    if( isset($_GET['post']) && get_post($_GET['post']) && isset($_GET['action']) && 'edit' == $_GET['action'] )
        $post = get_post($_GET['post']);

    if( isset($post) 
        && !empty($post->post_type)
        && is_object_in_taxonomy($post->post_type, 'category') 
    ){
        foreach ( (array) get_the_category($post->ID) as $cat )
        {
            if ( empty($cat->slug ) )
                continue;

            $submenu['edit.php'][] = array(
                __('Back'), // menu title
                'edit_posts', // menu cap
                'edit.php?category_name=' . $cat->slug // menu link
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that just now and it doesn't work. The link in the sidebar disappears.

Comment: OK, check the updates. `$post` is not available on admin_menu hook, so need to retrieve it first.

Comment: It works! Thank you Shazzad. I appreciate it. Works perfectly